# Umbraco: Adding Fields to Users / User Types

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

What's the best way to extend the users area?  I want to add a field to the User Types where you must select an Administrator (by User Type) for each particular type.  I don't see any way to extend this area, does it have to be done in the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to extend a User to add more properties that I"m aware of.  You could create a new table in the Umbraco database and then use an XLST Extension or C# class to get the extended properties in a Razor macro or User Control.  However, you would have to create a custom folder in the Users section (or a custom section) to allow editing of the extended properties in Umbraco.