# Limit the amount of pages of each node in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to add count limitations to the content tab nodes? 
For example you have following node structure:

```
Home
|
|-- About
|
|-- Projects
    |
    |-- Project 1
    |
    |-- Project 2
|
|-- News
    |
    |-- News 1
    |
    |-- News 2
|
|

...
```

**Customer 1:**

Chooses the standard hosting package and gets 10 projects and 10 news items.

**Customer 2:**

Chooses the ultimate hosting package and gets 1000 projects and 1000 news items.

How can I limit the customer to only create up to a certain projects and newsitems?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the Umbraco Application Event Handler to catch the ContentService.Created event (the ContentService.Creating event is obsolete since it offers the same options).

```
public class AppEvents : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        ContentService.Created += ContentService_Creating;
    }
}
```

Then you could write an extension to the Created event that would check the type of page being created and apply restrictions according to the current user's UserType.  This would just mean that you cancel the event and prevent the page from being created.

```
public void ContentService_Creating(IContentService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.NewEventArgs<IContent> e)
{
    switch (e.Entity.ContentType.Alias)
    {
        case "ProjectAlias":
        case "NewsItemAlias":
            var contentService = Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current.Application.Services.ContentService;
            var userTypeAlias = UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser.UserType.Alias;
            var count = contentService.GetChildren(e.Entity.ParentId).Count();
            if (string.Equals(userTypeAlias, "Standard") && count >= 10)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else if (string.Equals(userTypeAlias, "Ultimate") && count >= 1000)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This is untested but I've used similar methods before to prevent pages from being created/deleted by certain users.

Comment: looks very nice, I will try this. One more thing, how can I set the amount in the back-end of umbraco? You do it hard coded, but I would like to make it as a property to set in some kind of license module

Comment: If you're looking to add custom properties to User Types in the CMS then I don't think there's an easy way to do that at the moment.  I think the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847272/umbraco-adding-fields-to-users-user-types?lq=1) is still valid, although it's a couple of years old.  You could add a new table to the database and then add a custom tree to the Users section which uses an API controller to access the new database table.  [Here's an example](https://github.com/perploug/UkFest-AngularJS-Demo/blob/master/App_Code/PeopleTreeController.cs).

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't cancel a 'created' event.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the package **[NodeRestrict](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/noderestrict/)**.

You can specify through a config file the maximum nodes a user can create under a parent node. E.g. For your case:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nodeRestrict propertyAlias="maxChildNodes" showWarnings="false">
  <rule 
    parentDocType="News" 
    childDocType="NewsChild" 
    maxNodes="10"
    showWarnings="true"
    customMessage=""
    customMessageCategory=""
    customWarningMessage=""
    customWarningMessageCategory=""
    >
   </rule>
</nodeRestrict>
```